# derivative of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have a problem understanding derivatives in multiple variables.

When I take a look at the function $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ I notice, that it is not partial derivable in $(0,0)$, because
$\partial_x f(x,y) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $\partial_y f(x,y) = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. So it can't be totally derivable in $\mathbb R^2$, but in $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus\{(0,0)\}$ (because the partial derivatives are continuous)?
But WolframAlpha says $f'(0,0) = (0,0)$. Why?

Comment: what is $\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{0}{t}$? Is it $0$? Or something else?

Comment: Thanks, I see that my limits don't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to compute the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$. For instance,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(t,0)-f(0,0)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{t^2}}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}{\frac{|t|}{t}}
$$

So, you see that $f'_x(0,0)$ does not exist, regardless of what Wolfram may say.